# What is an express template engine?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am new in express and angular development. I know how to render a view by using angular. My question is:

1) Why render a view via express by using a template engine reather using angular?

2) Can I combine template engine with angular views? Why does I need that? How can I do that?

3) It is possible develop complex interfaces by using template engines?

Thanks

Comment: That's far too broad and open-ended. You need to be a lot more specific and I suggest you start by **reading** about express & angular.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides somehow it's own "template engine" through directives.
There is no real need to use a template engine inside an AngularJS app.

Wiring up AngularJS with express.js is (imho) not a real deal, since AngularJS brings its own routing mechanism. You'd rather use express.js to route between different AngularJS sites (and here I mean real sites, not different AngularJS views).

Summed up: Express.js runs on the serverside, AngularJS runs in the browser. They don't really affect each other.